# How could I do something before navigate to other view by NavigationLink?

Tags: swiftui, navigationlink

Let me show the simple source code:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {        
            NavigationView {
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(message: "Detail Page #2") ) {
                        Text("Go detail Page #2 >")
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Index Page #1")
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Before navigate to MyDetailView, I want to do something, for example: save some data, or change some variable...

How could I do that?

It may be a simple question, but I really don't know.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got a simple method to resolve that:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {        
            NavigationView {
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(message: "Detail Page #2") ,isActive: $isPresented) {
                        Text("Go detail Page #2 >")
                            .onTapGesture
                             {
                                 //Do somethings here
                                 print("onTapGesture")
                                 //Navigate
                                 self.isPresented = true
                             }
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Index Page #1")
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and is a simple and effective way of achieving the goal.

Comment: I've been adding '.onTapGesture' to so many items.....never thought to add it to the text of the NavigationLink. Thank you. Using this to dismiss keyboard prior to navigation....couldn't find another simple solution beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle methods from lifecycle using:

```
   .onAppear {
        print("ContentView appeared!")
    }
```

And:

```
   .onDisappear {
        print("ContentView disappeared!")
    }
```

check this tutorial:  https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-respond-to-view-lifecycle-events-onappear-and-ondisappear

So, you can use the `.onDisappear` to perform any action you need

Comment: Another question: If I have two NavigationList, for example: cancel and save, how could I know which NavigationList I click?

Comment: NavigationLink you mean? You can handle this with a `@State var`. If you click save, you modify it for "save" and the same with cancel. Idk if tha'ts what you want.. sorry, I didn't got your question